# How to backup an AOSP project on GitHub

Tags: android, git, github, android-source

I have an Android project composed of AOSP, and other code in an Ubuntu environment. As you know, I used git and its associated tool repo to download AOSP according to the procedures on android source site. Now I want to have a way of controlling the changes I make to the environment. I have read about Git, but perhaps not enough to know what is the best way to do this. Maybe I already have this capability just by using Git locally? So my question is: What is the best way to save state in my build environment please, and how do I save this on Github as a remote backup repository? I believe I need to have a .gitignor file to exclude object files? Basically I have a WORKING_DIRECTORY with all of my code in there. That directory has a .repo and .git directory in it.

Comment: " As you know, I used git ..." - well, no, we don't )

Comment: You probably need to read this, it has all the answers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find that most or all of your changes will be under certain branches. For me, I develop roms for the Nexus 9 so a lot of my changes are under device/htc/flounder. The common branch is frameworks/base/ where I also make a lot of changes.

To this end I have two separate git repos that store these:
https://github.com/seanashmore/frameworks_base
https://github.com/seanashmore/device_htc_flounder

To create these, I created a github account. Then went to each of he top level folders i.e. frameworks/base and device/htc/flounder and ran the command 'git init'. This initializes those directories as git repositories. You also need to create the repos on your github account, this will give you url's for you to 'push' your code to.

The initial push of frameworks/base will take some time as it is quite large, but once you have done that first push its very handy to keep track of your code changes and all the other benefits that git brings.

A very handy git guide can be found here: http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/

If you need any more information or help just ask.